# How many concurrent sessions does Oracle database support?

Tags: oracle, dbms

I want to have an application linked to an Oracle database. The users will request data through the app, and the app will access the database and retrieve the info.

My question is: how many concurrent sessions will the system support?

Answer (score 2):

The number of concurrent sessions is determined by the values of `PROCESSES` and `SESSIONS` initialization parameters, provided that your hardware can handle that many of them. You can check the limits and current utilization by querying `v$resource_limit`:

```
select * from v$resource_limit where resource_name in ('processes','sessions')
```

Typically you don't want to have a one-to-one mapping between application sessions (instances) and database sessions; you would employ a connection pool, implemented either in the database driver itself or in the application middleware, which allows more efficient use of session resources on the database server.

Comment: what do you mean by a connection pool? and the concurrent session are related to a single user or multiple users?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool

Comment: Even a single user can open multiple concurrent sessions.

Comment: so what is the maximum capacity for connection pool? and how many concurrent session a single user can have